# Angular 2 Router Navigate using component path and not full path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have Routes and child routes using the following structure

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'component-one', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'component-one', component: ComponentOne },
  { path: 'component-two/:id', component: ComponentTwo,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'child-one', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'child-one', component: ChildOne },
      { path: 'child-two', component: ChildTwo }
    ]
  }
];
```

Now If I want to navigate to the child route `childTwo` so inside `componentTwo` I have the following.

```
 <a [routerLink]="['child-two']">
```

And this works.

But what if I want a button to do the same instead of a link.

So I tried an alternate method using a button, as follows

```
<button (click)="toClicked()">Two</button>
```

Then I have the following click handler

```
toClicked(){
  this.router.navigate(['component-two','child-two']);
}
```

As you can see If I have the link I just have to provide the child route `childTwo` but using a button with a click handler I will have to provide the parent component `component-two` as well as the child `childTwo`

Can I navigate by just passing the child component using click handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

toClicked(){
    this.router.navigate(['./child-two'], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

Take a look at the [relative routes chapter in the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#relative-navigation) for more details.